# What is $f '(x)$ for $f(x)=(x-3)^3$?

Tags: calculus

> What is $f '(x)$ for $f(x)=(x-3)^3$?

I'm thinking it is $3x^2 - 18x + 27$
but my textbook says it is $3x^2 - 18x - 27$

Comment: You are right, the textbook apparently has a typo.

Comment: Textbooks were made by humans. If humans make mistakes, so do textbooks.

Comment: If you want to double check anything you're not sure of, use WolframAlpha. Just type in "derivative of (x-3)^3" into the search box and it will compute it for you. It's much quicker than asking on MSE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) we have:

$f'(x)=3(x-3)^2\times \frac{d}{dx}(x-3) = 3(x-3)^2$

And $3(x-3)^2 = 3(x^2-6x+9) = 3x^2-18x+27$

**You are right**. Your textbook is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
f(x)=U^n\\
f^{\prime}(x)=nU^{\prime}U^{n-1}
$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
f^{\prime}(x)&=3(x-3)^{2}\\
&=3(x-3)(x-3)\\
&=3(x(x-3)-3(x-3))\\
&=3(x^2-3x-3x+9)\\
&=3(x^2-6x+9)\\
&=3x^2-18x+27\\
\end{align}$$